# If $f$ is a function on $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)f'(b)>0$, then $f$ must vanish at least at one point in $(a,b)$. Is it true?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a function on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f'(a)f'(b)>0$, then $f$ must vanish at least at one point in $(a,b)$.
Is it true?

Comment: what about $f: [1,2]\to [1,2]$, where $f(x)=x$?

Comment: Sorry! Pls look at my edited question.

Comment: So, for example, if $a=b$, and this is not excluded by the conditions, then $(a,b)$ is empty and there is no point to be "at least one point"

Comment: Now you will at least also need something like continuity of $f$ on $[a, b]$. If that's not the case, let $f: [0, 2] \to \Bbb R$ be given by $f(x) = x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, and $f(x) = x - 2$ for $x \in (1, 2]$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$? Assuming it is, drawing a little picture will quickly show that $f$ must have a root in $(a,b)$.

Comment: question is actually what I posted,but now it is clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)= x- \left\lfloor x \right \rfloor-{1\over 2}$ is a counter example. It has a root as 0.5 and 1.5 but no root in between.

This happens because the given function is not continuous. If it's given to be continuous, you can show that there exists a $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $[a,b]$ by using the fact that the given function is differentiable at the end points such that $f(c_1)f(c_2)<0$ . Now by intermediate value theorem, this will have a root in between $( c_1 , c_2 )$ and therefore also in $[a,b]$

Comment: If we only assume the function to be differentiable at the endpoints, I guess we can't use the mean value theorem? 
But we can find $c_1, c_2 \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c_1)<0$ and $f(x_2)>0$, and thereby find a root by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions do not specify $a\neq b$. If $a=b$ there is no point in the (empty) open interval at which the conclusion of $f$ vanishing at "at least one point" can be true.

It might be that the context implies $a\neq b$, but in the absence of this, $a=b$ gives a counterexample even in the case where $f$ is differentiable in an open interval containing both $a$ and $b$ or continuous in $[a,b]$ (examples of potential additional conditions).

Other counterexamples are in some ways more significant, but I have put this just to show that some care has to be taken about basic assumptions - here, the same point can have two different names.

Comment: If someone writes that a function is defined in $[a,b]$ and there exists $f’(a)$, it is implicit that $a<b$ otherwise, if the function was defined only on $\{a\}$, it could not be differentiable at $a$.

Comment: @Angelo The question was modified in relation to a comment I made and deleted, which made it at least comprehensible as a question. But it is still underspecified - I assume $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, for example, though this is nowhere stated apart from in the "real analysis" tag. For your interpretation, derivatives at endpoints are one-sided, so there is a lot assumed. I specifically suggested the case of $f$ differentiable in an open interval containing $a$ and $b$ to allow for two-sided derivatives at $a$ and $b$.